# Transição de slides

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-ui

Tenho esse código (modelo de Internet) de transição de slide automático. Gostaria de saber como que eu colocaria o efeito "Fade".

```
<img class="mySlides" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSFh65LFf2UPsjvNxBuBISj4C4WC3K9FtKfc1_vcC9pvi_oqWAdgw" style="border-radius:10px; width:515px; height:370px">
<img class="mySlides" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQYpuQvYCQfZEBtvib6zTi69oY0CYmwtQGspxeKuLHJsfpb_8P4QQ" style="border-radius:10px; width:515px; height:370px">
<img class="mySlides" src="https://www.infoescola.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/bauru-cidade_748974265-1000x750.jpg" style="border-radius:10px; width:515px; height:370px" >

<script type="text/javascript">
var slideIndex = 0;
carousel();

function carousel() {
    var i;
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      x[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    slideIndex++;
    if (slideIndex > x.length) {slideIndex = 1}
    x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
    setTimeout(carousel, 2000); // Change image every 2 seconds
}
</script>
```

Comment: Vc quer uma resposta em JS porque está estudando JS e gostaria de ver o código, ou uma resposta apenas com CSS sem precisar de JS já te atenderia?

Comment: Nesse link tem um slideshow feito só com CSS caso te interesse https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/288556/bug-no-slideshow-se-ficar-muito-tempo-fora-do-separador/288581#288581

Comment: Adicionei no código alguns cometários explicativos. Espero que ajude a entender.

Answer (score 1):

Se está usando jQuery (tagou [jquery-ui](/questions/tagged/jquery-ui)), use as funções `.fadeIn()` (para mostrar) e `.fadeOut()` (para ocultar), mas inclua um CSS para ocultar todas as imagens menos a primeira:

```
.mySlides:not(:first-of-type){
   display: none;
}
```

Ou pode usar (preferível):

```
.mySlides:not(:nth-child(1)){
   display: none;
}
```

> Aqui no snippet o `.mySlides:not(:nth-child(1))` não funcionou!

**Veja:**

```js
var slideIndex = 0;
carousel();

function carousel() {
   var x = $(".mySlides"); // seleciona todos os elementos com a classe .mySlides
   if(slideIndex){ // se slideIndex for diferente de 0
      $(".mySlides:visible").fadeOut(function(){ // oculta com efeito de fade a imagem visível
         $(x[slideIndex-1]).fadeIn(); // mostra com efeito de fade a próxima imagem
      });
   }
   slideIndex++;
   if (slideIndex > x.length) slideIndex = 1;
   setTimeout(carousel, 2000); // Change image every 2 seconds
}
```

```css
.mySlides:not(:first-of-type){
   display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="mySlides" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSFh65LFf2UPsjvNxBuBISj4C4WC3K9FtKfc1_vcC9pvi_oqWAdgw" style="border-radius:10px; width:515px; height:370px">
<img class="mySlides" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQYpuQvYCQfZEBtvib6zTi69oY0CYmwtQGspxeKuLHJsfpb_8P4QQ" style="border-radius:10px; width:515px; height:370px">
<img class="mySlides" src="https://www.infoescola.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/bauru-cidade_748974265-1000x750.jpg" style="border-radius:10px; width:515px; height:370px" >
```

> **Obs.:** Por padrão as funções *fade* demoram 400 milissegundos para rodar, neste caso, caso queira que a transição ocorra em exatos 2
>   segundos (2000 milissegundos no `setTimeOut`) entre uma imagem e outra, aumente o valor para
>   `2400` para compensar.